# How to dynamically set font family in Jasper Report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I tried

```
            <textElement markup="html">
                <font fontName="$P{contentFont}"/>
            </textElement>
```

and put `Arial Unicode MS` for `$P{contentFont}`
but iReport throws:

```
Error filling print... Font '$P{contentFont}' is not available to the JVM. 
See the Javadoc for more details. 
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font '$P{contentFont}' 
    is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.
```

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontUtil.checkAwtFont(FontUtil.java:347)

So I guess  is no way to pre-define font family at run-time? Is there anyway to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature to achieve what you want,

Have a look at Jasper Report [Style Templates](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/templates/)

Jasper Report has [font extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html) which support some fonts which includes,

```
DejaVu Sans
DejaVu Serif
DejaVu Sans Mono
```

I you want to use fonts other than Jasper Font Extesnions, take a look at [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-fonts).

Hope this helps.